# Calculating mediation from total effect, mediation from interaction, and pure indirect effect?

Tags: regression, survival, mediation, epidemiology

I am conducting a mediation analysis using a 4-way decomposition method (med4way command in STATA). According to (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30452641/), after getting the results of the 4-way dcomposition, the formula to calculate mediation is ((mediated interaction + pure indirect effect)/total effect)*100.

My question is should I include the mediated interaction if in the formula if it is not statistically significant?

For example:
total effect = -0.1530608, p=0.001

mediated interaction = 0.0304828, p=0.830

pure indirect effect = -0.0721859, p=0.000

Many thanks,
Andrew